# Calling pre-definend methods from Main()

Tags: c#

What am I doing wrong here:
Trying to access a defined method but getting an error saying: 
"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'bag' of 'Program.PutInTheBag(ref List)' ... "

My method ( PutInTheBag() ) doesn't require any argument, how can I told my program to ignore that?
If that is not possible, how do I access my bag list from all my methods (including Main() as well)?
P.S. Plz don't judge too hard, I'm just a beginner...

```
 class Program
{
    List<string> bag = new List<String>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Välkommen till ryggsäcken!");

        while (true)
        {
            MainMenu();
            int userChoice;
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userChoice);

            if (userChoice == 1)                
                PutInTheBag();                                   

            else if 
            // some code

            else
            {
                //some code
            }
        }

    }        

    private static void PutInTheBag(ref List<string> bag)
    {
        Console.Write("Lägg till ett föremål: \t");
        bag.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Innehållet sparat! \nTryck en valfri knapp för att komma till huvudmenu");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: but it does require an argument... so either make it not do that or pass it an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My method ( PutInTheBag() ) doesn't require any argument, how can I
>   told my program to ignore that?

change the method signature from this:

```
private static void PutInTheBag(ref List<string> bag)
```

to this:

```
private static void PutInTheBag()
```

> how do I access my bag list from all my methods (including Main() as
>   well)?

Also change this:

```
List<string> bag = new List<string>();
```

to this:

```
static List<string> bag = new List<string>();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A `ref` parameter still needs to have a value passed to it. The `PutInTheBag` methods does not automatically know you may intend to use it with the `bag` variable from `Program`.